# The modifiers and what they do

Tags: modifiers

I'm creating flash cards and I want to have flashcards on blenders modifiers. Can someone please list all the modifiers blender has and their functions? Keep in mind that I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: Hello :). All available modifiers are listed in the [Blender Manual right here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/index.html). Complete with extensive explanation and examples. Enjoy.